# What to do when my new manager sends me a file with no context, except for "update this"?

Tags: communication

What to do when my new manager sends me a file with no context, except for "update this"?
The file was put together by my old manager, without my involvement/input whatsoever.

Comment: Why isn't teh answer as simple as reply back "What do you need doing on this file, never worked on it before" ?

Comment: You ask them what they want updated and what audience it is for.

Comment: Are there any dates/contact information/information that need to be updated? If you really can't figure it out, you're wasting precious time by asking us. You should be picking up the phone and asking your boss about this. You shouldn't be asking us. We even have less context than you do!

Answer (score 13):

> What to do when my new manager sends me a file with, no context except
> for "update this"? The file was put together by my old manager,
> without my involvement/input whatsoever.

If you understand what needs to be done, you do it.

If you don't understand what needs to be done, you ask your new manager what to do.